# wicked form with nested model form in rails 3.0.9 and rvm 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

In one module of my project I have used nested form and in that nested form I want to use wicked forms with wicked

Reference : Ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast

views > notices > _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@notice) do |f|%> 
  #notice attributes
<%= f.submit, "Next">
<% end %>
```

I created a notice_step controller and in that controller I have written

```
class NoticeStepsController < ApplicationController
   include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :agendaa
   def show
     @notice = Notice.new
     render_wizard
  end
end
```

and in create action in notice controller

```
  def create
    @notice = Notice.new(params[:notice])
      if @notice.save 
      session[:notice_id] = @notice.id 
      redirect_to notice_steps_path 
      else 
        render :new 
    end   
   end
```

notice_step > agenda.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@notice, url: wizard_path) do |f| %> 
 < div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :agendas do |builder| %>
    <%= render "notices/agenda_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
   <%= link_to_add_fields "Add agenda", f, :agendas %>
 < /div>
 <% end %>
```

Nested model is working..... but on clicking on next button it shows me following error

```
It is giving me SyntaxError in User_steps#show compile error
/home/kipl/Desktop/cus_notice/app/views/user_steps/agendaa.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...ppend=  form_for(@notice, url: wizard_path) do |f| @output_b...
                              ^
/home/kipl/Desktop/cus_notice/app/views/user_steps/agendaa.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

The colon notation of a Hash (`:`)is for Ruby 1.9 only.
You should use the rocket notation (`=>`).